# Inconsistency in this module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see the only difference in `this` module, Python3 has wrapped parenthesizes `(, )` for the print function. I noticed an inconsistency in lengths of that module in two different python versions.

```
import this; print(len(open(this.__file__).read()))
# 1003
```

```
len(open('/usr/lib/python2.7/this.py').read())
# 1002
```

These are the outputs in python3x version. If the only difference is print function with parenthesizes, why the output is not 1004 and it is 1003?

Comment: does this happening for all the files?

Comment: I don't know but I don't think so. @deadshot

Comment: @Fathih if it is not happening for all files then it's not a "Inconsistency in module"?

Comment: Why is this important to programming? Why not just view the files side-by side in any reasonable diff-viewer, which will show you the differences? The only answer just shows that you have to count carefully.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an inconsistency.
The final line of the [file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/this.py) in Python 2 is:

```
print "".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s])
```

The [file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/this.py) in Python 3:

```
print("".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s]))
```

Note how the first `(` replaces the space between the `print` and string. The `)` is the only added character.

Comment: Thank you this is amazing